# How to replace same symbols with two diferent <remarks> in two different conditions using REGEX in Python

Tags: python, regex

Hi I was trying to make one regular expression to replace the Punctualtions and other symbols with  and if the punctuations repeats then e.g. eg. "!!!" => "! ")

for the input :

```
....    
??  
>>>>>
^   
%
```

If I apply the below regular expressions then:

```
text = re.sub(r'([@+*&%$#\\|_=`~>.,?!"</)({}-]){2,}', r'\1 <REPEAT>', text) # Mark punctuation repetitions (eg. "!!!" => "! <REPEAT>")
text = re.sub(r'([@+*&%$#;:\^\]\[\\|_=`~>.,?!"</)({}-])', r'\1 <PUNC>', text) # Mark punctuation as <PUNC>
```

I am getting the output like :

```
['. <punc> < <punc>repeat> <punc>', '! <punc> < <punc>repeat> <punc>', '? <punc> < <punc>repeat> <punc>', '> <punc> < <punc>repeat> <punc>', '^ <punc>', '% <punc>']
```

Where as it should be:

```
['. <repeat> ', '! <repeat> ', '? <repeat> ', '> <repeat>', '^ <punc>', '% <punc>']
```

Can any one please let me know the solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Included in both regex are these symbols `<>`. After you substitute `<repeat>` in the first regex, the second subsitutes it to `< <punc>repeat <punc>`. Solution: _take these `<>` out of the second regex_ ?? Or, you could just use a lookbehind `(?<=[@+*&%$#;:\^\]\[\\|_=\`~>.,?!"</)({}-])` and replace with `<punc>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest avoiding to process the string twice: use a single regex with 2 alternatives and process the match inside a lambda expression:

```
import re
texts = ["....", "!!!!", "??", ">>>>>", "^", "%"]
rx_repeat = r'([@+*&%$#\\|_=`~>.,?!"</(){}-]){2,}'
rx_punc = r'[@+*&%$#;:\^\]\[\\|_=`~>.,?!"</(){}-]'
pat = r'{}|{}'.format(rx_repeat, rx_punc)
texts = [re.sub(pat, lambda x: r'{} <REPEAT>'.format(x.group(1)) if x.group(1) else r'{} <PUNC>'.format(x.group()), text) for text in texts]
print(texts)
# => ['. <REPEAT>', '! <REPEAT>', '? <REPEAT>', '> <REPEAT>', '^ <PUNC>', '% <PUNC>']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7gYz5W)